# Populate relationship in SQLAlchemy with `query().join()`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following models

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "as"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey("bs.id"))
    b: Mapped[B] = relationship()


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bs"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    c_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey("cs.id"))
    c: Mapped[C] = relationship()
    x = mapped_column(Integer)


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cs"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    y = mapped_column(Integer)
```

I want to query `A` objects with constraints on the associated `.b.x` and `.b.c.y` value, and I want the resulting `A` objects to have populated fields (not lazy).

1. If I use `joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c)`, I cannot apply constraints directly:

```py
select(A)
  .options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c))
  .where(B.x == 0, C.y == 0)
```

```sql
SELECT `as`.id, `as`.b_id, cs_1.id AS id_1, cs_1.y, bs_1.id AS id_2, bs_1.c_id, bs_1.x
FROM `as` LEFT OUTER JOIN bs AS bs_1 ON bs_1.id = `as`.b_id LEFT OUTER JOIN cs AS cs_1 ON cs_1.id = bs_1.c_id, bs, cs
WHERE bs.x = ? AND cs.y = ?
```

and as you can see, the constraints are not on the joined table, so the query is incorrect.

2. If I use `.has()`, I get the proper results but this creates am inefficient query (in practice I have many more constraints and large tables):

```py
select(A)
  .options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c))
  .where(
    A.b.has(
      and_(B.x == 0, b.c.has(C.y == 0))
    )
  )
```

```sql
SELECT `as`.id, `as`.b_id, cs_1.id AS id_1, cs_1.y, bs_1.id AS id_2, bs_1.c_id, bs_1.x
FROM `as` LEFT OUTER JOIN bs AS bs_1 ON bs_1.id = `as`.b_id LEFT OUTER JOIN cs AS cs_1 ON cs_1.id = bs_1.c_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM bs
WHERE bs.id = `as`.b_id AND bs.x = ? AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM cs
WHERE cs.id = bs.c_id AND cs.y = ?)))
```

with `(EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...))` which are inefficient and not needed here.

3. If I use `.join()`, I can get clean request, but then the relationship fields do not get populated automatically:

```py
select(A)
  .join(B, A.b_id == B.id)
  .join(C, B.c_id == C.id)
  .where(B.x == 0, C.y == 0)
```

```sql
SELECT `as`.id, `as`.b_id
FROM `as` INNER JOIN bs ON `as`.b_id = bs.id INNER JOIN cs ON bs.c_id = cs.id
WHERE bs.x = ? AND cs.y = ?
```

and as you can see, the fields for `A.b` and `A.b.c` are not included, so accessing `A.b` will trigger a new request (same for `A.b.c` of course).

4. If I combine `.join` and `joinedload`, the request is not valid:

```py
select(A)
  .join(B, A.b_id == B.id)
  .join(C, B.c_id == C.id)
  .where(B.x == 0, C.y == 0)
  .options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c))
```

```sql
SELECT `as`.id, `as`.b_id, cs_1.id AS id_1, cs_1.y, bs_1.id AS id_2, bs_1.c_id, bs_1.x 
FROM `as` INNER JOIN bs ON `as`.b_id = bs.id INNER JOIN cs ON bs.c_id = cs.id LEFT OUTER JOIN bs AS bs_1 ON bs_1.id = `as`.b_id LEFT OUTER JOIN cs AS cs_1 ON cs_1.id = bs_1.c_id
WHERE bs.x = ? AND cs.y = ?
```

contains 4 joins instead of two.

---

Is there a way to get `A.b` and `A.b.c` populated as-if I used `joinedload`, but using a SQL requests similar to `.join()`?

Comment: will you show the generated queries for each of your attempts and explain what you don't like about them?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Fixed code and added generated query and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import contains_eager

query = (
    select(A)
    .join(A.b)
    .join(B.c)
    .where(and_(B.x == 0, C.y == 0))
    .options(contains_eager(A.b), contains_eager(A.b, B.c))
)
```

---

Original answer:

```py
select(A)
    .join(A.b)
    .join(B.c)
    .where(and_(B.x == 0, C.y == 0))
    .options(joinedload(A.b).joinedload(B.c))
```

Comment: I don't think that works (unless `.options` has different behavior if used after a `.join`, because I tested with `.options` first) because the generated query uses two different JOIN.

Comment: I tested the `contains_eager` on the toy example from the question and it seems to work. I will try to apply it to the real use-case and if it works I'll accept this answer, otherwise I'll edit my question with a proper MRE.

Comment: I tried the `contains_eager` version on the real tables and it worked, thanks. I took the liberty to edit the answer to put the working version first.

Comment: @Holt Note that the outer parentheses are redundant when you chain method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired outcome by combining join and options. like this,

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased, joinedload

B_alias = aliased(B)
C_alias = aliased(C)

query = (session.query(A)
         .join(B_alias, A.b_id == B_alias.id)
         .join(C_alias, B_alias.c_id == C_alias.id)
         .options(joinedload(A.b.of_type(B_alias)).joinedload(B.c.of_type(C_alias)))
         .filter(B_alias.x == 0, C_alias.y == 0))

result = query.all()
```